# passing function to the view in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

Can I pass a function to the view in CodeIgniter? The function basically checks if the session value is set. For example:

```
public function is_logged(){
    $logged = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    if ($logged){
        return true;
    } else {
        redirect('index');
    }
}
```

Now i want to place this function on some of my view. so how can i pass this function to the view?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to pass it in your view, CI uses the MVC pattern so all your check must be done in your Controllers. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: note that `$this->session->userdata('user_id');` returns `false` so `isset($logged)` will always return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different approach, much like @atno said: you're using MVC pattern, so doing this kind of checks in your view is 'logically' wrong as well as going against a DRY approach.

I would do the check in controller, using the function I have in the model, and load the appropriate view according to the results:

```
class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller {

     function index() //just an example
     {
        $this->load->model('mymodel');  
        if($this->mymodel->is_logged())
        {
          $this->load->view('ok_page');
        }
        else
        {
          $this->load->view('not_logged_view');
          //OR redirect('another_page','refresh')
        }
    }
}
```

In your model:

```
 function is_logged()
 {
    $logged = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

    if ($logged)
    {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
 }
```

If it's someting you need to do programmatically, for every method of a controller (like checking for being logged in), you can check inside the constructor:

```
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    // check code here
  }
```

In this way you'll have the check before any method of the controller is called, i.e. upon controllers' initialization.

**UPDATE**: 
using a model can be overkill here, you can just check what $this->session returns:

```
function index() { // or mypage() or whatever

if($this->session->user_data('user_id'))
{
  $this->load->view('ok_page');
}
else
{
  $this->load->view('not_ok_page');
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a question, shouldnt the is_logged function be in controller? because it just checks if the session has a value user_id. It doesnt interact with the database. (if i understand correctly, in the model we have the functions which interact with the database)? thanks.

Comment: @Roman well, I would place in a model just to avoid repeating it over and over..Anyway, given the concisness of the function, you could also write `if($this->session->userdata('user_id') { //load a view } else { //load another view }` which is even better maybe. BTW, models aren't for db only, usually any data processing can be put there

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing that. Just have this code directly in your layout, or just have it in your view.

You could also create a helper : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html